# How to display a GIcon in a Gtk.Treeview using CellRendererPixbuf

Tags: treeview, gtk, gtk3

I'm adding my column dynamically using [CellRendererPixbuf](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf) with the following code:

```
    private void add_column (TrackColumns type) {
        var column = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn () ;
        column.title = type.get_title () ;
        var renderer = type.get_cell_renderer () ;
        column.pack_start (renderer, true);
        // 
        column.set_attributes (renderer, (type == TrackColumns.ICON) ? "pixbuf" : "text", type) ;

        treeview.insert_column (column, -1);
    }
```

The method `TrackColumns.get_cell_renderer` is

```
    public Gtk.CellRenderer get_cell_renderer () {
        if( this == ICON )
        {
            var result = new Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf ();
            //icon_renderer.follow_state = true;
            return result ;
        }
        if( this == TITLE )
        {
            var result = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
            result.height = TrackListView.COLUMN_HEIGHT;
            return result ;
        }

        var result = new Gtk.CellRendererText ();
        result.height = TrackListView.COLUMN_HEIGHT;
        result.xpad = TrackListView.SPACING;
        return result ;
    }
```

I want my `CellRendererPixbuf` to display a `GIcon`.

The code above doesn't display anything and gives me the following warning:

```
unable to set property 'pixbuf' of type 'GdkPixbuf' from value of type 'GIcon'
```

**What is going wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

The proper code is:

```
    column.set_attributes (renderer, (type == TrackColumns.ICON) ? "gicon" : "text", type) ;
```

The [set_attributes](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeViewColumn.set_attributes) method defines the name of the property of the renderer to set and the value to use when the cell is rendered.

In my code, I have only two types of renderers: `CellRendererText` and `CellRendererPixbuf`.

Because I want the Gtk.Treeview to set [CellRendererPixbuf.gicon](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf.gicon) with my column value, I need to pass `"gicon"` (and not `"pixbuf"`) when my column is of type `TrackColumns.ICON`.

The rest of the time, I use a `CellRendererText` so I need to use [CellRendererText.text](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.CellRendererText.text) and thus pass `"text"`.

All this (and more) is explained [there](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cellrenderers.html#cellrendererpixbuf).